# GAE appengine-web.xml per environment without no compile

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an Java application on Google App Engine.
I would like to change the configurations of appengine-web.xml without compile the package again, bacause I have to pass the same final package (war) for each environment. (DEV, HOM, PRD).
My problem is, I would like to change the instance-classe in some environments because on HOM I can use a less power instance than PRD.

There is a way to set this values in with variables or another way to do it?
I could do it with maven and replace the file, but I want to keep the same final package for each environment.

Comment: I usually keep one configuration per environment (under version control) and, at deploy time, I unpack the war, replace the respective configuration files and finally execute gcloud or appcfg pointing to the exploded war directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FábioUechi, I think that is no possible do it without unpack. I will let the post open, but I really think that is not possible. Thanks!